# Jenkins: Illegal reflective access by org.testng.xml.XMLParser in

Tags: jenkins, testng

I am trying to run the same program in Jenkins using `run.bat` file.

It throwing me below error:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.testng.xml.XMLParser (file:test ng path) to constructor com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.testng.xml.XMLParser
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bsh/EvalError
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:99)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:508)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:142)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:106)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1103)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:955)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:900)
    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1182)
    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1146)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.EvalError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 10 more
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

My `run.bat` file has

```
java -cp "lib/*;bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

command

I have set `JAVA_HOME` to my jdk in configurations